# Which javascript event runs when the element is painted blue?

Tags: javascript

Which javascript event runs when the element is painted blue?

**Example**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5yWJ.png)

Comment: can you be a little specific, like background color? and how are you setting the color?

Comment: @DevMayukh I mean, which event works when I select the object with the mouse? (When I select the object with the mouse, it is painted blue.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a selectionchange event, fired at document level. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/selectionchange_event

There is how it works :

```js
//Can only be listened at document level
document.addEventListener('selectionchange', event => {
     //the selection changed
    document.activeElement; //Is the selected element.

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-pare-ne1iq?file=/src/index.js). But it didn't work.

Comment: @vsay I edited my answer to provide you an example. You can't listen for selectionchange event on a DOM node. It's only fired at document level.

Comment: I get it now. With the "document.getSelection().focusNode" method, I can directly access the element I selected. Thanks for everything.